# How can I encrypt text using a public key WITH passphrase?

Tags: ios, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

Now I can encrypt a text using the method in this [tutorial](http://johnny.logdown.com/posts/69881-rsa-encryption-method-on-ios). (Sorry for it is in Chinese only but I think you can understand the post by its code snippets).

It encrypts using a public key WITHOUT passphrase. How can I encrypt my text using a public key WITH passphrase?

---

Update 1:

I can read a public key without passpharse using the code below:

```
certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, ( __bridge CFDataRef)publicKeyFileContent);
if (certificate == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Can not read certificate from pub.der");
    return nil;
}
```

The problem is - How can I read a public key WITH passpharse in iOS?

---

Update 2

The communication between server and iOS app is using https

Other than https both backend and app has their public key and private key for secure communication.

Steps for their communication:

1. App owns public key (with passphrase) from server
2. App generates a public key (with passphrase) and a private key (when app is used for first time)
3. when app sends data (a JSON with 3 parameters) to server, app will send a public cert generated by app (JSON parameter 1) + app generated public key passphrase (JSON parameter 2) + message encrypted by public key from server (JSON parameter 3)
4. Server can read the received message (decrypted by server side private key)
5. Server will send response message after receive a JSON. The message is encrypted by public key generated by app

So the secure connection is established from server to every single app. And ensure correct individual app won't receives message that is not intended for them.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish because RSA(isometric key encryption) does not have a passphrase, just a public and private key which are not derived from a passphrase.

Comment: @zaph Thanks for your answer and reply. What exact I want to do is to make the iOS app can read a public key with a passphrase so I can use the public key for encryption. (I have edited the question to make it clear)

Comment: 1. Why do you want to keep the public key secret? Only the person with the private key can decrypt data encrypted with the public key. The private key must be kept secret. 2. If you want to encrypt the use AES symmetric encryption with a key derived from the passphrase with PBKDF2 Bothe of these are available in Common Crypto. 3. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I understand your questions... But I don't want to change the structure of the backend... so I want to follow it. I am difficult to explain the backend structure to you in detail.   Using a public key with passphrase provides a bit more security but not very secure actually...  Can you provide me the code for using a public key with passphrase?

Comment: "Can you provide me the code for using a public key with passphrase?": No, there is no such standard thing. There may be some mashup they came up with and you will have to find out the full details. Very likely the backend developers did not understand cryptographic security. An aside: I mentioned the concept of encrypting the public key with a passphrase to a [CISSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certified_Information_Systems_Security_Professional) cryptographic domain expert and the response was: "That's crazy".

Comment: @zaph Thanks your for reply... It may crazy... I have updated my question. See update 2 for the flow of communication. You can tell me if there are any not reasonable part in the flow. :)

Comment: You need to ask about the passphrase, that is non-standard. In example the OpenSSL command to generate a key-pair is: `openssl genrsa 4096`, note that there is no passphrase. The public key can be extracted from the public key.

Comment: Since the server will have a private key for each app instance this really does not make sense, it would be easier just to use AES and a symmetric key to encrypt the data. Note: The data length encrypted with a public key must be less than the key size in bytes.

Comment: Just talked to my crypto domain; you should ask for an architectural diagram of the cryptography. If they don't have one they need to create one. Without one creating the client-side is going to be difficult and problematic.

Comment: Thanks!! And one more thing. Is HTTS itself is secure enough? or I need both HTTPS and AES to achieve appropriate security level?

Comment: https is secure enough. In face the way it works is to encrypt the data with a symmetric algorithm such as AES and a random key which is encrypted with a asymmetric key such as RSA. But https does not provide authentication of the client and to ensure against MITM attacks the server certificate must be pinned.

Comment: @zaph Is that reasonable to use OAuth 2.0 in my case?

Answer (score 0):

RSA  encryption is an asymmetric encryption algorithm. When encrypted with the public key it can only be decrypted with the associated private key. There is no passphrase.

In general data encryption usage symmetric key encryption such as AES is used with a key that is derived from a password/phrase with PBKDF2.

In general when using asymmetric encryption the text would be encrypted with a symmetric algorithm such as AES using a random one-time key. The key would is encrypted with the asymmetric algorithm and both the symmetric encrypted text and the asymmetric encrypted key are both sent to the other end. The receiver reverses the process using the private key.

Note that asymmetric encryption is both slow and the data to be encrypted is limited to the key size. This is why it is generally used just to encrypt a key or very limited data.